# Django __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) when trying to delete

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I get this error: `__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)` , but ONLY if the user is created through a HTTP Post Request. If I create the user through the normal Django Admin Panel I can delete the user.

I also tried to print every type of the HTTP Post income and get this:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

So every field is a str or an integer. What could be the problem?

This is my model:
models.py

```py
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    userid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
    
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["firstname", "lastname", "email"]


    objects = MyAccountManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)

    # For checking permissions. to keep it simple all admin have ALL permissons
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    # Does this user have permission to view this app? (ALWAYS YES FOR SIMPLICITY)
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
def registration_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            account = serializer.save()
            data['response'] = 'successfully registered new user.'
            data['firstname'] = account[0].firstname
            data['lastname'] = account[0].lastname
            data['email'] = account[0].email
            data['username'] = account[0].username
            data['age'] = account[0].age
            token = Token.objects.get(user = account[0]).key
            data['token'] = token
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
            print(data)
        return Response(data)
```

serializer.py

```py
class RegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'username', 'age', 'password', 'password2']
        extra_kwargs = {
                'password': {'write_only': True}
        }   

    def save(self):
        account = Account(
                firstname = self.validated_data['firstname'],
                lastname = self.validated_data['lastname'],
                email = self.validated_data['email'],
                username = self.validated_data['username'],
                age = self.validated_data['age'],
            )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']
        username = self.validated_data['username']
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords must match.'})

Not     errors = dict() 
the     try:
error   validate_password(password=password)
->
->      except ValidationError as e:
->          errors['password'] = list(e.messages)
            
        if errors:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)

        account.set_password(password)
        account.save()
```

Comment: share more details and code

Comment: if you want to return a string try to convert it to a string like this "str(string_variable)"

Comment: Yeah I have this. I added my model. If you need more just write

Comment: what function is the error and show me the code where you call the function

Comment: This is the problem. I don't know. I don't get an error **where** the error is

Comment: does the error happen by the if or the else statement, try the print the data outside the if-else but before the return to get more details maybe

Comment: add your serializer please

Comment: make sure all the post fields are not empty

Comment: But for the custom user model you are advised to inherit from `AbstractUser`, not `AbstractBaseUser`

Comment: @YankiSegal This is not the problem. Everything is filled in

Comment: @MahmoudAdel This isn't the problem. Until today everyhing worked fine. But I really didn't changed anything big :/

Comment: So what did you change?

Comment: @YankiSegal This, where I wrote (This is not the error -> -> ->) this part:   errors = dict() 
  try:
   validate_password(password=password)

  except ValidationError as e:
   errors['password'] = list(e.messages)
   
  if errors:
   raise serializers.ValidationError(errors)

  account.set_password(password)
  account.save()

Comment: `data = serializer.errors` convert this to string? one of the errors returns nonetype

Comment: Still don't work :/

Comment: do an empty check and add some string if empty

Comment: Yeah :/ Had an None type Field Thank you. You can post your command as an answere :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add something to Yanki Segals answere:

None type is also empty in Python. Maybe you have a function or whatever where a value will be set to None. None is not None -> It's empty for Python.